# When I rotated the simulator, there are many black blocks around UIWindow

Tags: ios, uiscreen

How to get the black blocks disappear?

And after the rotation, the black blocks disappear.

[image: screenshot]

AppDelegate Source File:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    bar = [KodUserCenterBar instance];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Header File:

```
@interface KodUserCenterBar : UIWindow

/**获取单例
 */
+ (instancetype)instance;

/**显示工具栏
 */
+ (void)show;

/**隐藏工具栏
 */
+ (void)hide;

/**显示功能视图
 */
+ (void)showFunctionView;

/**隐藏功能视图
 */
+ (void)hideFunctionView;

@end
```

Source File:

```
#define WIDTH self.frame.size.width
#define HEIGHT self.frame.size.height



#define kScreenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
 #define kScreenHeight [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
 #define kBarWidth 200
 #define kBarImageViewTag 100
 #define kBarItemGap 5
 #define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

 @interface KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger indexOfTabBar;
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *imageName;

 + (instancetype)objectWithTitle:(NSString *)title indexOfTabBar:(NSUInteger)index imageName:(NSString *)imageName;

@end

@implementation KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject

+ (instancetype)objectWithTitle:(NSString *)title indexOfTabBar:(NSUInteger)index imageName:(NSString *)imageName
{
    KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *obj = [KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject new];
    if (obj) {
        obj.title = title;
        obj.indexOfTabBar = index;
        obj.imageName = imageName;
    }
    return obj;
}

@end


@interface KodUserCenterBar()
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
    UIViewController *_rootVC;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *itemsOfBar;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat initWidth;
@property (atomic, strong) UIButton *button;

@end

static KodUserCenterBar *static_instance = nil;
static BOOL isShowMenu = NO;

@implementation KodUserCenterBar

+ (instancetype)instance
{
    if (static_instance == nil) {
        static_instance = [KodUserCenterBar new];
        [static_instance addTopButton];
    }
    return static_instance;
}

+ (void)show
{
    [KodUserCenterBar instance].hidden = NO;
}

+ (void)hide
{
    [KodUserCenterBar instance].hidden = YES;
}

+ (void)showFunctionView
{
    if (!isShowMenu) {
        [[KodUserCenterBar instance] clickBar:nil];
    }
}

+ (void)hideFunctionView
{
    if (isShowMenu) {
        [[KodUserCenterBar instance] clickBar:nil];
    }
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self makeKeyAndVisible];
        self.sd_x = 0;
        self.sd_center_y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height / 2;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onDeviceOrientationChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)itemsOfBar
{
    if (_itemsOfBar == nil) {
        KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *item1 = [KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject objectWithTitle:@"个人中心" indexOfTabBar:0 imageName:@"tb3_toolbaruser"];

        KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *item2 = [KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject objectWithTitle:@"游戏礼包" indexOfTabBar:1 imageName:@"tb3_toolbargame"];

        KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *item3 = [KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject objectWithTitle:@"系统公告" indexOfTabBar:2 imageName:@"tb3_toolbarmsg"];

        KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *item4 = [KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject objectWithTitle:@"游戏论坛" indexOfTabBar:3 imageName:@"tb3_toolbarbbs"];

        NSArray *data = @[item1, item2, item3, item4];
        _itemsOfBar = [NSArray arrayWithArray:data];
    }

    return _itemsOfBar;
}

- (void)onDeviceOrientationChange
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"is portrait");
        NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight);
        [self adjustWindowPosition];
        self.sd_center_y = kScreenHeight / 2;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"is landscape");
        NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight);
        [self adjustWindowPosition];
        self.sd_center_y = kScreenHeight / 2;
    }
}

- (void)addTopButton
{
    pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragBar:)];
    pan.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:pan];

    UIViewController *vc = [[KodBasicViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.rootViewController = vc;
    CGSize size = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_nor"].size;
    self.sd_width = size.width;
    self.sd_height = size.height;
    self.initWidth = size.width;

    _button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_nor"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    _button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickBar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _button.selected = NO;
    [_button becomeFirstResponder];
    [vc.view addSubview:_button];
}

- (void)clickBar:(id)button
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = 0.2;
    __weak typeof(_button) weakButton = _button;

    isShowMenu = !isShowMenu;
    pan.enabled = !isShowMenu;

    if (self.sd_center_x > kScreenWidth / 2) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:interval animations:^{
            self.sd_x = kScreenWidth;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (isShowMenu) {
                self.sd_width = kBarWidth + self.initWidth;
                _button.sd_right_x = self.sd_width;

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_bor_right"];
                image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 30, 1, 0)];
                UIImageView *rightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                rightImageView.image = image;
                rightImageView.sd_width = kBarWidth;
                rightImageView.sd_right_x = _button.sd_x;
                rightImageView.sd_center_y = _button.sd_center_y;
                rightImageView.tag = kBarImageViewTag;
                rightImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [self.rootViewController.view addSubview:rightImageView];
                self.sd_x = kScreenWidth;

                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_right"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_pre_right"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_pre_right"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [self addFunctionItems:NO];
            }
            else {
                self.sd_width = self.initWidth;
                _button.sd_right_x = self.sd_width;
                UIView *contentView = [self.rootViewController.view viewWithTag:kBarImageViewTag];
                [contentView removeFromSuperview];

                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_nor"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            }

            [UIView animateWithDuration:interval animations:^{
                self.sd_right_x = kScreenWidth;
            }];
        }];
    }
    else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:interval animations:^{
            self.sd_right_x = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (isShowMenu) {
                self.sd_width = kBarWidth + self.initWidth;

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_bor_left"];
                image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 1, 30)];
                UIImageView *leftImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                leftImageView.image = image;
                leftImageView.sd_width = kBarWidth;
                leftImageView.sd_x = _button.sd_right_x;
                leftImageView.sd_center_y = _button.sd_center_y;
                leftImageView.tag = kBarImageViewTag;
                leftImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [self.rootViewController.view addSubview:leftImageView];
                self.sd_right_x = 0;

                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_left"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_pre_left"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_act_pre_left"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

                [self addFunctionItems:YES];
            }
            else {
                self.sd_width = self.initWidth;
                UIView *contentView = [self.rootViewController.view viewWithTag:kBarImageViewTag];
                [contentView removeFromSuperview];

                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_nor"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [weakButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tb3_assi_pre"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            }

            [UIView animateWithDuration:interval animations:^{
                self.sd_x = 0;
            }];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)addFunctionItems:(BOOL)isLeft
{
    UIView *bgView = [self.rootViewController.view viewWithTag:kBarImageViewTag];
    if (bgView) {
        [self.itemsOfBar enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(KodUserCenterBarFunctionItemObject *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            if ([bgView viewWithTag:idx] == nil) {
                KodFrameTabBarItem *item = [[KodFrameTabBarItem alloc] init];
                item.tag = idx;
                item.title = obj.title;
                item.imageName = obj.imageName;
                item.sd_width = (bgView.sd_width - _itemsOfBar.count * kBarItemGap - 10) / _itemsOfBar.count;
                item.sd_height = bgView.sd_height;
                item.sd_center_y = bgView.sd_height / 2;
                item.sd_center_x = kBarItemGap + idx * (item.sd_width + kBarItemGap) + item.sd_width / 2;
                item.sd_center_x += isLeft ? 0 : item.sd_width / 4;
                [item addTarget:self action:@selector(clickItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [bgView addSubview:item];
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)clickItem:(id)sender
{
    [KodNavigationView showWithIndex:0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:[KodNavigationView instance]];
}

- (void)adjustWindowPosition
{
    if (self.sd_center_x < kScreenWidth / 2) {
        self.sd_x = 0;
    }
    else {
        self.sd_right_x = kScreenWidth;
    }
}

- (void)dragBar:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)p
{
    CGPoint panPoint = [p locationInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        if (_button) {
            _button.selected = YES;
        }
    }
    else if(p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        self.center = CGPointMake(panPoint.x, panPoint.y);
        if (panPoint.x < WIDTH / 2) {
            self.sd_x = 0;
        }
        else if (panPoint.x > kScreenWidth - WIDTH / 2) {
            self.sd_right_x = kScreenWidth;
        }

        if (panPoint.y < HEIGHT / 2) {
            self.sd_y = 0;
        }
        else if (panPoint.y > kScreenHeight - HEIGHT / 2) {
            self.sd_bottom_y = kScreenHeight;
        }
    }
    else if(p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if(panPoint.x <= kScreenWidth / 2) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                self.sd_x = 0;
            } completion:nil];
        }
        else {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                self.sd_right_x = kScreenWidth;
            } completion:nil];
        }

        if (_button) {
            _button.selected = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

@end
```

#### Root ViewController

Source File Of Root ViewController:

```
@interface KodBasicViewController ()

@end

@implementation KodBasicViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}



- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    UIWindow *window = self.view.window;
    [window bringSubviewToFront:window.rootViewController.view];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    UIWindow *window = self.view.window;
    [window bringSubviewToFront:window.rootViewController.view];
}

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't provided nearly enough information. Post the code that relates to auto-rotation, and info about the constraints on that window. (The word is "rotation", not "roration." I edited your post.)

Comment: Also any information you can provide about the view that is having the blocks appear around it.  They seem to be pretty regular, is this a custom UIView?  Are you using autolayout?

Comment: In addition to that, what makes you think these blocks are around the window and not part of the window itself ?

Comment: @A-Live yeah, you are right, i think it's part of the uiwindow.

Comment: @Duncan C Hello, I have post my code. could you help find the problem, and give me some advice, cause i'm still a beginner of iOS. Thanks!

Comment: in addition, i have upload the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
window.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the default background colour of UIWindow instance, and while your root view is doing rotation, those uncovered parts will be shown as black block as you said.

You can just set your desired background colour for your window (or make your root view's frame big enough to cover whole window while doing rotation, not recommended):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  ...
  [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: No, when i set the background color of the UIWindow, the black blocks still show up, and still be black. if i can change the blocks' color, i can make it to clearColor, but seems no function is provied! and this window is not the key window of application, so if make this window big enough to cover the whole screen, the view on it will not be at the edge of the screen.

Comment: @FrankWang _"... and this window is not the key window of application"_, u sure it's not the key window? so why there's `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` ? _"... if i can change the blocks' color, i can make it to clearColor "_ clear color won't works for the key window unless there's another UIWindow instance w/ color below it.

Comment: in AppDelegate file:bar = [KodUserCenterBar instance];the bar is also a UIWindow. it is caused the black block. self.window is the keywindow in AppDelegate class.i tried, bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; still so, nothing changed.